# What's the Java equivalent of C++'s STL Queue?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, queue

I was browsing through the [Java docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) to look for the Java equivalent for C++'s STL `Queue`, but all I found was an interface called `Queue` and a bunch of implementations I can't make heads or tails of.

Does Java have an implementation for `Queue` that's just a FIFO data structure without the added bells and whistles? I only need the `enqueue`, `dequeue` and `front` operations and the data structure should allow duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Queue` will work. Use any implementation you like. `LinkedList` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for example.

`enqueue` = `offer(..)`
`dequeue` = `poll()`
`front` = `peek()`

Answer (score 3):

That docs page lists all the classes that implement the interface.  So, for instance, you can do the following (**DISCLAIMER: hasn't been near a compiler**):

```
Queue<E> q = new LinkedList<E>();

E x1 = new E();
E x2 = new E();
E x3;

q.offer(x1);
q.offer(x2);

x3 = q.poll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `LinkedList`. Sure, it has lots of functionality you don't need, but it's not hurting you either.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.LinkedList` class is probably what you want, and the methods would be "add", "remove", and "element".

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is a double-ended queue. See the [Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and it's implementing classes.